# ESP32 SD writes but doesn't append

Tags: esp32, sd-card

I've got a microSD module adapter from the far east, and so far so good, and although it can create files using `writeFile`, it does not append messages. It returns `true`, i.e: message appended successfully but when you read the file on the computer or when ESP32 reads on reboot, it's blank.

This is how I call the function:

```
char* sdFileName = "/v.ea";
if (appendFile(SD, sdFileName, "Heyy")) {
//success
} else { 
//failed
}
```

This is the modified, `appendFile` function:

```
bool appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, const char * message) {
  bool appendSuccess = false;
  if (DEBUG == 1) {
    Serial.print("Appending to the file: ");
    Serial.println(path);
  }
  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);
  if (!file) {
    appendSuccess = false;
    if (DEBUG == 1) {
      Serial.println("Failed opening the file.");
    }
  }
  if (file.print(message)) {
    appendSuccess = true;
    if (DEBUG == 1) {
      Serial.println("Appended succesfully.");
    }
  } else {
    appendSuccess = false;
    if (DEBUG == 1) {
      Serial.println("Appending failed.");
    }
  }
  file.close();
  if (appendSuccess) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I've even tried the `writeFile` function with `file.seek(EOF)` but no luck.
When calling `appendFile` for the first time, this appears:

```
[W][sd_diskio.cpp:149] sdCommand(): token error [17] 0x17
Appending succesfully.
```

When the `appendFile` is called for the second time, this appears in serial monitor:

```
[W][sd_diskio.cpp:149] sdCommand(): token error [17] 0x17
[W][sd_diskio.cpp:149] sdCommand(): token error [17] 0x5
[W][sd_diskio.cpp:149] sdCommand(): token error [17] 0x5
[E][vfs_api.cpp:265] VFSFileImpl(): fopen(/sd/v.ea) failed
Appending failed.
```

I am using two SPI devices: MFRC522, and before calling SD's functions, I do a `digitalWrite(SD_SS, LOW)` to "enable" the SD functions till it completes its operations and returns back to `HIGH` to disable it.

The example in `SD(esp32)` works fine - writing, appending, deleting, renaming, etc. all work well.

Comment: Did you initialize SD with `SD.begin()`?  How do you handle the MFRC522? You have to disabled it, when the SD reader is active on the SPI bus. Where do you use writeFile? From the code I see, there's is nothing wrong, beside it is too complex. If there is a problem with the code, then you missed to show us the part where the problem is located. When you said the SD(esp32) works fine, do you mean example code for ESP32 where you don't use additional hardware?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, yes, it is obvious, otherwise, even the `writeFile` would fail, and it'd report that SD mount failed first and foremost. Also yes, as I said, when I disable MFRC522, I enable SD, complete operations, then disable SD and enable MFRC522. The problem, as I suspect is in `appendFile`, as Serial monitor shows the [W] and [E], respectively. And also yes, SD(esp32) from File > Examples works well for all operations.

Comment: P.S.: I use `writeFile` if `readFile` returns false, that is, when the file does not exist, it invokes `writeFile(SD, sdFileName, "")`. Specifically, when `fs.open(path)` returns false, I instruct to create a new file by invoking `writeFile`.